# The specified password for user account 'root' is not valid, or failed to connect to database server when installing wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, iis, virtualbox, web-platform-installer

I installed windows server 2016 on virtual machine on virtualbox and then I want to install wordpress in iis by using the web platform installer. but the installuation failed and shows this error "The specified password for user account 'root' is not valid, or failed to connect to database server"

Comment: there are a lot pf steps for doing that, so follow the tutorial https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_on_Microsoft_IIS

Comment: still the same problem :(

Comment: you are much to wage, is your mysql server running, can you connect for example with mysql workbench. as you can see in the steps in the links you must enter the mysql keays and the wordpress admin passpharase, so i9n with step are you getting your error,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please use the command line tool to check whether the root password is correct.

Secondly, please check whether MySQL Connector/Net is installed. If it is not installed, please install it. If it is installed, please check its version.